# Как объединить 2 массива объектов?

Tags: javascript

Допустим приходят 2 массива объектов

```
arr1 = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Петр"
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "ВасЯ"
 },
]

arr2 = [
 {
  id: 2,
  diagnosis: "рак"
 },
 {
  id: 1,
  diagnosis: "Розовый лишай"
 },
]
```

Как можно объединить их по одинаковому id?

Comment: получение данных в таком виде уже само по себе неверное.

Comment: Если массивы будут длинные, где много клиентов, то скорость обработки таких массивов будет желать лучшего. Лучше сразу подумать как получить нормальный массив с объектом, где будет и айди, и имя, и диагноз, иначе какой-то костыль.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Петр"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "ВасЯ"
}];

const arr2 = [{
  id: 2,
  diagnosis: "рак"
}, {
  id: 1,
  diagnosis: "Розовый лишай"
}];

const arr3 = arr1.map((y) => Object.assign(y, arr2.find((x) => x.id === y.id)));

console.log(arr3);
```